# How to get read_stream for my page tab app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Recently i have tried to submit a app (which is a page tab app) that include read_stream permission. My app was denied and the review state that:
"This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission."

So my question is can i get my read_stream permission for my page tab app (which i consider to be web platform) in any possible way?
And if I want to get access to logged-in users posts (to be more specific, posts that user share from my fanpage), is there any other workaround because i have tried using user_status and unable to get it work. 
The Developer Documentation also state that /{user}/posts & /{user}/feed is strictly requires read_stream permission. (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/feed/)

Comment: No it is not possible.

Comment: this question gets asked a lot on stackoverflow, and the answer is always already in the question ;)

Comment: So there is no way to check if a user share a post on my fanpage, is there?

Comment: _“to check if a user share a post”_ – why would you have to “check” this in the first place? I hope you are aware that Platform Policies forbid you from “rewarding” users for sharing in almost every conceivable way.